# Been there, done that (got the T-shirt)

Tags: traduction, anglais, expressions-idiomatiques

En anglais, l'expression « [*been there, done that*](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/been-there-done-that.html) » signifie que le locuteur sait de quoi parle son interlocuteur, qu'il a déjà vécu une situation analogue. Il y a une connotation plus ou moins marquée de dérision ou de lassitude : la situation est bien connue, le locuteur n'a pas besoin qu'on lui décrive les détails, il est blasé. C'est une expression [assez récente](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=been+there+done+that&year_start=1970&year_end=2010&corpus=0&smoothing=3) mais largement [passée dans la langue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Been_there,_done_that_%28disambiguation%29). On rallonge assez souvent en « *been there, done that, got the T-shirt* » pour marquer que .

[image: Been there, done that, got the T-shirt.]

Est-ce qu'il y a une expression analogue en français ? On peut dire « je connais », mais c'est très neutre. Comment rendre mieux le côté blasé voire légèrement dérisoire ?

Comment: Dans mon sociolecte, une suite de borborygmes « Djaf', djaf', djaf' » ou un sonore « Djafé ! » (accentué sur la première syllabe) sera très bien compris. Existe aussi en version « D'javu ! »

Comment: @JPP Wow, j'avais jamais entendu ça, pour ma part ! ^^

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Si la situation en question est désagréable, négative, on peut utiliser le familier **« j'ai déjà donné »**. Exemple :

> - Do you plant to come to the boss’ barbecue on Saturday? — Been there, done that, no thanks!
> - Tu viens à la soirée qu'organise le patron samedi ? — Non, merci, j'ai déjà donné !

Ou, dans un style un peu différent, si le sens peut être celui de la reconnaissance d'une expérience partagée, **« je connais ça »**, ou **« bienvenue au club ! »**, ou même les deux :

> - I drank so much after she left that I don't remember what happened next. — Yeah, been there, done that.
> - J'ai tellement bu que je n'ai aucun souvenir du reste de la soirée. — Je connais ça, bienvenue au club !

Comment: Sinon, ça m'a aussi fait pensé à **veni, vidi, vici**, mais qui est moins proche du sens d'origine, alors je le mets en commentaire…

Comment: F'x: du pur français.

Comment: Ah, « bienvenue au club », très bonne idée. Pas « veni vidi vici » par contre, en générale « been there done that » implique qu'on n'a pas *victum*.

Comment: J'aime bien « bienvenue au club ! » malgré le fait qu'on ne va le dire que si l'interlocuteur est concerné et découvre la situation ou vient de le faire. J'ai des collègues qui ont employé « been there, done that » dans des situations où toutes les personnes présentes avaient déjà vécu la chose.

Comment: vēnī, vīdī, hăbŭī [tuniculam](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/la/wiki/Tunicula)

Answer (score 4):

Je trouve que le *J'ai déjà vu ça* du [commandant Turbo](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/fr/wiki/Natacha#Le_commandant_Turbo) rend bien l'idée de blasé, de la personne qui a déjà tout vu, tout entendu.

Comment: ou "Déjà vu" tout simplement?

Answer (score 1):

Je vois pas d'expression toute faite, et j'opterais pour une traduction quasi littérale :

> J'y étais,
>   J'ai fait ci,
>   J'ai fait ça.
>   (V'la l'T-shirt).

Je pense que l'effet « blasé » ressort pas mal.

Comment: C'était une proposition pour un T-shirt équivalent en français. (Ça fonctionne pas du tout pour la traduction de l'oral :-/)

Answer (score 1):

*La vie est un éternel recommencement.* Mais ça donne l'impression qu'on a déjà vécu la situation plusieurs fois.

Comment: Ah non, « *been there done that* » implique la familiarité du locuteur, mais pas qu'il l'a fait plusieurs fois.

Comment: Nous sommes bien d'accord -- d'où mon « mais... ». Il n'empèche qu'il y a des contextes où c'est ce que je dirais.

Answer (score 1):

Des suggestions négatives, pour indiquer qu'on en a fait l'expérience, et que ça a fortement déplu :

> Tu m'as pris pour un bleu ?  (Do you think I'm a newbie?)
>
> Je me suis déjà fait avoir ("I got tricked once already")
>
> Une fois, ça suffit ! ("Once was enough!")
>
> On ne m'y reprendra pas ! ("I won't be tricked again")

Au contraire, pour indiquer qu'on est blasé, qu'on juge inutile de retenter l'expérience, on peut dire :

> Je suis blasé ("I know all the ins and outs")
>
> Ça casse pas trois pattes à un canard ("it's very unimpressive")
>
> Mouais (a bored yes)
>
> Veni, vidi, vici
>
> T'étais pas né que je IMPARFAIT déjà ("you weren't even born that I already…")

Comment: Oui, et on pourrait ajouter "Ça va cinq minutes", pour indiquer que l'on est blasé.

Answer (score 1):

Je l'ai aussi vu traduite par « j'ai eu ma dose ».

Answer (score 0):

Je pense que la bonne traduction serai plutot: "je suis (déjà) passé par là."

Answer (score 0):

Peut-être que "rien de neuf sous le soleil" peut convenir.